# How to determine queries per hour executed by a particular Mysql user

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to implement user based quota system in mysql to limit `MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR`  for a particular user. I have an option to set this limit via `MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10`.
But my problem is that I want know that how many queries a user has executed this hour.  I followed [This Thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/how-to-determine-mysql-queries-per-day) but this is for global statistics of dba.  I want this information for every user of my database. I am sure that mysql is storing this schema somewhere but after a lot of scrutinizing some of Databases like `information_schema` , `performance_schema` , `mysql` I cant figure out how it will be achieved.

Comment: You will have to enable the `general_query_log`. You can direct the logging to a database table. Most likely you can then access this information from the log. Note that this log gets very big pretty quickly, so you will have to regularly, get relevant summarized data out of it and clean up. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html